# Modify plot sizes in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, graph, ggplot2

I am using multiplot to plot 2 pie charts that share a legend on one page.

```
plot1<-ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(1),y=values,fill=names))
    +geom_bar(stat="identity",width="1")
    +coord_polar(theta="y")
    +theme(legend.position="none")
plot1<-ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(1),y=values2,fill=names))
    +geom_bar(stat="identity",width="1")
    +coord_polar(theta="y")
multiplot(plot1,plot2,cols=2)
```

When I do this, the plot without the legend is much bigger than the plot with a legend.

1) Is there a way to control this directly through multiplot()?
2) How do I control the width and length of my original plots?

Thank you all!

Comment: Use `plot_grid` from the `cowplot` package and use the `align` argument to get equal panel sizes.

Comment: Is there a way I control the sizes directly from the ggplot line?

Comment: What package is the `multiplot` function from? Have you tried `gridExtra::grid.arrange`?